# Use iTextSharp to save a PDF to a SQL Server 2008 Blob, and read that Blob to save to disk

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm currently trying to use iTextSharp to do some PDF field mapping, but the challenging part right now is just saving the modified file in a `varbinary[max]` column. Then I later need to read that blob and convert it into a pdf which I save to a file.

I've been all over looking at example code but I can't find exactly what I'm looking for, and can't seem to piece together the [read from file to iTextSharp object] -> [do my stuff] -> [convert to `varbinary(max)`] pipeline, nor the conversion of that blob back into a savable file.

If anyone has code snippet examples that would be extremely helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The need to deal with a pdf in multiple passes was not immediately clear when I first started working them, so maybe this is some help to you.

In the method below, we create a pdf, render it to a `byte[]`, load it for post processing, render the pdf again and return the result.

The rest of your question deals with getting a `byte[]` into and out of a `varbinary[max]`, saving a `byte[]` to file and reading it back out, which you can google easily enough.

```
public byte[] PdfGeneratorAndPostProcessor()
{
  byte[] newPdf;

  using (var pdf = new MemoryStream())
  using (var doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4))
  using (PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, pdf))
  {
    doc.Open();

    // do stuff to the newly created doc...

    doc.Close();
    newPdf = pdf.GetBuffer();
  }      

  byte[] postProcessedPdf;
  var reader = new PdfReader(newPdf);

  using (var pdf = new MemoryStream())
  using (var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, pdf))
  {
    var pageCount = reader.NumberOfPages;
    for (var i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
    {
      // do something on each page of the existing pdf
    }

    stamper.Close();
    postProcessedPdf = pdf.GetBuffer();
  }

  reader.Close();
  return postProcessedPdf;
}
```